# CSS-grid insertion of column in middle of grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been stuck on a CSS-grid issue. I have a grid that could have 4 or 5 columns (and n number of rows). The third column is optional (so it might not always be there).

I'd like to just insert the third column automatically - but keep the given column widths of the existing columns.

Is there a way to do this?

In the example below, I have columns 1, 2, 4, and 5, with some given widths. I'd like for the extra column (if needed) to appear in position 3 (at width, say 2fr) and keep the widths of the other columns.

Example:
Grid without the 3rd column:
https://jsfiddle.net/L83b4o1x/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-1">
    <h2>one</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <h2>two</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <h2>four</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <h2>five</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 3fr 1fr 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  flex: 2;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: use a normal 5 column grid and manually place the items into the grid. Alternativly fill the 3rd column always with an empty div that has the css attribute `display:hidden;` thatw ay it will fill up the space but not being visible.

Comment: It'd be best done with JavaScript, but if you really wanna stick to CSS, you could try using `:nth-child(4)` and `:nth-child(3)` on the `1fr` element to apply different styles to it, depending on whether the "middle" element is present or not (without the middle element, it's gonna be the 3rd child, with the middle element, the 4th). The styles you could be applying are `grid-area` for example, or `grid-column-start` to let the `1fr` element take up the middle column if it's not present.